# Numpy version of Pandas dropna with subset - trying to remove rows if the last column in my array contains NaN

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to remove rows from a numpy array if a certain column (ie. the last column in my array) contains NaN. NaN values in other columns are acceptable, just not the last column.

I know this is possible by converting to a pandas dataframe and using `df.dropna(subset=['lastcolumn'])`. I am wondering if it is possible to do this in numpy since converting to Pandas and using dropna is quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.isnan()` works but need to specify which column can't have NaN:

```
a = np.array([[1,np.nan,3], [4,5,np.nan], [7,8,9]])
print(a)

[[1.0000 nan 3.0000]
 [4.0000 5.0000 nan]
 [7.0000 8.0000 9.0000]]

b = a[~np.isnan(a[:,2:3]).any(axis=1)]
print(b)

[[1.0000 nan 3.0000]
 [7.0000 8.0000 9.0000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
In [1856]: import numpy as np
In [1857]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,np.nan], [7,8,9]])

In [1858]: a
Out[1858]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5., nan],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])

In [1859]: a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=1)]
Out[1859]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
```

**EDIT**

If `NaN` needs to be removed from specific column only, you need this:

```
In [1870]: a[~np.isnan(a[:, 1:2]).any(axis=1)]
Out[1870]: 
array([[ 4.,  5., nan],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

This will remove `NaN` from first two columns only.

Comment: What if a NaN in the second column is acceptable, but if there is a NaN in the third column then the corresponding row should be removed?

Comment: My example shows `NaN` in the 3rd column itself. Solution works properly.

Comment: OK try ```a = np.array([[1,np.nan,3], [4,5,np.nan], [7,8,9]])``` but only the second row should be removed, the first row is acceptable. I don't think you're understanding what I'm asking - Nan's in the first or second column are OK, only remove the row if the NaN is in the third column.

Comment: It just is, because of the nature of the data and what I'm trying to do. I just can't accept NaN in the last column of my dataset. That's why I asked for the numpy equivalent of dropna with subset.

Comment: But your question says nothing like that.

Comment: "I'm trying to remove rows from a numpy array if certain columns contain NaN." I have edited it so its very clear now.

Comment: OK, I have edited my question to make it extremely clear. Do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: @lara_toff I've edited my answer. Just needed to filter array based on columns.